# Visual Studio Emulator for Android only installs platform API 19

Tags: android, azure, google-api, virtual-machine, emulation

When you install the VS emulator you can see that in the progression logs it is only installing platform API 19. However, the documentation advertises it can install more than that. The site gives a vague message about google APIs have changed (yeah so helpful). I can't find any documentation confirming that this is what is expected.

Docs I found so far that are of no help:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/cross-platform/troubleshooting-the-visual-studio-emulator-for-android?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN
- https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/

Im using an Azure VM and so far using this emulator is the only one that works with Android studio without being incredibly slow. I have hyper-v enabled and WindowsHypervisorPlatform turned on.

This is all I get in the log as well simply trying install a profile outside of 19:

```
4> 10/13/2022 9:25:23 AM : [Informational] Waiting to install device...
4> 10/13/2022 9:25:23 AM : [Informational] Installing Device: 5.7" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone , Version: 1.0.60404.1
4> 10/13/2022 9:25:23 AM : [Informational] Downloading and installing prerequisites
4> 10/13/2022 9:25:23 AM : [Informational] Installing Platform: Marshmallow (API 23), Version: 1.0.60404.1
4> 10/13/2022 9:25:23 AM : [Critical] An error occurred that prevented the operation from completing successfully.
4> 10/13/2022 9:25:23 AM : [Critical] An error occurred that prevented the operation from completing successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @jusTech you can use the android studio as a secondary option. It has all API levels.
link
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator

Comment: Yeah , they run so slow to the point they are unusable to me.